# gdalbuildvrt error 1: unable to find 'location' in DBF

Tags: gdalbuildvrt

I'm trying to create a vrt file with several shapes which I had created previously with gdal_contour (all of them only have 1 feature):

```
gdalbuildvrt -input_file_list tiles.txt vrtFile.vrt
```

But I got the next error:

```
ERROR 1: Unable to find field `location' in DBF file `D:\shapes\shape01.shp'.
```

After check the shapes in Qgis I discovered all the features only have the field 'ID' (with the value 0). So I tried with the option -tileindex with their IDs:

```
gdalbuildvrt -tileindex ID -input_file_list tiles.txt vrtFile.vrt
```

But then I obtained another error:

```
0...10...20...30...40...50ERROR 4: 0: No such file or directory 
Warning 1: Can't open 0. Skipping it
...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
ERROR 4: 0: No such file or directory
Warning 1: Can't open 0. Skipping it
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found an alternative for creating a vrt for these shapes files. Using ogrmerge.py it's feasible create not only a vrt but also a merged shape with all your files.

An example:

```
ogrmerge.py -f VRT -o merged.vrt *.shp
```

You can find all the documentation in the gdal wiki:
https://gdal.org/programs/ogrmerge.html

Regards